# Finding code only used in special classes via NDepend

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ndepend, static-code-analysis

I am trying to get rid of dead code in our codebase using NDepend. Since we are using dependency injection I want to find interfaces (and the implementations) only used in classes that deriving from the registry base:

```
public class PresenterRegistry : Registry
{
    public PresenterRegistry()
    {
        For<IExamplePresenter>().Use<ExamplePresenter>();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a little bit I created a query that is working in the way I need:

```
// <Name>Interfaces registered but potentially not used</Name>
warnif count > 0 
from t in JustMyCode.Types
from i in JustMyCode.Types
where t.DeriveFrom("StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry")
   && i.IsInterface
   && t.IsUsing(i)
   && i.NbTypesUsingMe < 3 // one using for implementation, one in registry
select i
```

Not as much code as I expected :-) This query isn't cover any eventuality but it is a good start.

Nevertheless: Patrick, thanks for your help!

---

You are welcome Rico :)  Btw, this code rule can be rewritten this way to be ran in *O(N)* instead of *O(N^2)* (N being the number of *JustMyCode.Types*). This optimization is achieved thanks to the magic [UsedByAny()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsSequenceUsage~UsedByAny.html) method. This rule also provides a more detailed result.

```
warnif count > 0 
let registryDerived = JustMyCode.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry"))
from i in JustMyCode.Types.UsedByAny(registryDerived)
where i.IsInterface &&
      i.NbTypesUsingMe < 3 // one using for implementation, one in registry
select new { i, 
             registryDerivedUser = i.TypesUsingMe.Intersect(registryDerived),
             i.TypesUsingMe }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you are asking for.

*I want to find interfaces (and the implementations) only used in classes that deriving from the registry base:* The following query matches application interfaces and classes used by any type that derive from `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`:

```
let registryDerived = Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("Microsoft.Win32.Registry"))
from t in Application.Types.UsedByAny(registryDerived)
select t
```

..and with the next query, you also get derived types and implementations of interfaces, matched in the previous query:

```
let registryDerived = Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("Microsoft.Win32.Registry"))
from t in Application.Types.UsedByAny(registryDerived)
let tDerived = t.DerivedTypes
let tImpl = t.TypesThatImplementMe
select new { t, tDerived, tImpl }
```

... or to list them all:

```
let registryDerived = Application.Types.Where(t => t.DeriveFrom("Microsoft.Win32.Registry"))

let tUsed = Application.Types.UsedByAny(registryDerived)
let tDerived = tUsed.SelectMany(t => t.DerivedTypes)
let tImpl = tUsed.SelectMany(t => t.TypesThatImplementMe)

from t in tUsed.Union(tDerived).Union(tImpl)
select t
```

Btw, `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` is sealed, so it is not class you are talking about. But you can replace it with your own class name, prefixed with namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Thats not exactly what I need: The example above give me all the types that are used from my registry base type. But I need to know the code that is **only** used in the registries. Do you see what I mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: *the code that is only used in the registries* do you mean the code used in the .NET Fx class *Microsoft.Win32.Registry* and classes used by *Microsoft.Win32.Registry* and classes used by ...  and so on? Or do you mean the key accessed in the registry?

Comment: Hello. No I mean code that is used in types of the StructureMap.Configuration.DSL.Registry. It is for the configuration of our dependency injection container. My aim is to find types and interfaces that are only used in these classes and in no other place in our codebase. This would mean than that the found types are just registered but not used, so it is dead code that properly can be deleted.

Since we are using dependency injection and TDD it is hard to find dead code, because the code is used at least by test classes and the registration for the DI container, as mentioned aboved. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, at no time you mentionned StructureMap, hence my confusion on Registry meaning?! NDepend doesn't read the StructureMap or other DI Fx file so far. But you can still write a program that 1) read the DI Fx file 2) use the NDepend.API to resolve types found in the DI Fx file, and then see their usage. http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html

Comment: Ok sorry for the missing information. But i still think it is not relevant. We are using for the configuration of StructureMap classes that inherits from the registry base class (not xml, please see the example in my initial post). Maybe it was little bit confusing to associate my question with the concrete use case (StructureMap). The same question could be: I need to find interfaces that is used **only** in any derivation of MyOwnBaseClass (like IExamplePresenter the example above). Do you see now what I mean? Sorry again for any misunderstanding.